# Excel COUNTIF increment date for pasting

Tags: excel, countif

I have a transaction table with two columns- ID and Date. Each id is unique and never repeated.

I want to count the number of transactions for each day of the past few years, without typing the formula for each day. When I try to pull down the formula =COUNTIF(B2:B5000, "1/1/17") to cells below, it changes the cell range rather than the date.

Comment: Is a pivot table an option?

Comment: Trying this, will report back.

Comment: If you are going to be adding data to the Range being used, then I would strongly suggest putting it into a Table (select your data including column headings and press ctrl+t).  Doing so let's you use the syntax =COUNTIF(Table1[[ID]:[Date]],[@[Date]]). Now when you add data to your table, the formula will always be correct and you get the additional benefit of your formula being self-commenting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 =COUNTIF($B$2:$B$5000,DATE(2017,1,ROW(A1)))
```

Comment: This locks the range, but doesn't increment the date.

Comment: @RickP then perhaps use `DATE(2017,1,ROW(A1))` instead of `"1/1/17"`.